# Modifying Observable Collection elements efficiently

Tags: c#, observablecollection

Basically I have an Observable Collection in my class and a static integer keeping track of how many elements there are in the collection. Every element in the collection has a unique ID starting from 1 up to the total number of elements.

What I want to do is, take out an element with a random ID, and then change the IDs of the succeeding elements accordingly so the IDs run continuously from 1 to the total number of elements. So for example if I have 5 elements and I remove the element with ID number 3, then I need some code that will modify the ID property of element with ID 4 and change it to 3, and modify the ID property of element with ID 5 and change it to 4, so all the IDs are in order without gaps.

I thought of doing something like this:

```
var matches = MyObject.MyCollection.Where((myobject) => myobject.UniqueId.Equals(ID_value_of_removed_item_plus_one))
foreach (MyDataType CollectionItem in matches)
{
   MyDataType CollectionItemCopy = ColectionItem
   CollectionItemCopy.UniqueId--;
   MyCollection.Remove(CollectionItem);
   MyCollection.Add(CollectionItemCopy);
}
```

But I can't help but imagine there's a more efficient way to go about doing this. I know the Observable Collection isn't a suitable choice for this kind of application but the thing is the elements are bound to a ListView so I can't use any other type of generic collection.

Comment: Instead of ObservableCollection you can use List<T> with manually RaisePropertyChanged after finishing your foreach. Thus you will update your view only one time instead of `matches.Count`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get all matches at once, then subtract one of the ID. There is no need to remove and add it again, since you are just adding and removing the same item. At the end, remove the original item.

```
var matches = MyObject.MyCollection.Where(myobject => myobject.UniqueId >= ID_value_of_removed_item_plus_one);

foreach (MyDataType CollectionItem in matches)
{
   CollectionItem.UniqueId--;
}

MyCollection.Remove(itemToDelete);
```

Comment: Thanks. It works, but I don't get how changing the element in the matches object automatically reflects in the original collection. Is there some kind of implicit referencing when using LINQ syntax or something?

Comment: It is the same object referenced, so you edit the existing one.

Comment: LINQ doesn't copy the items. It just makes a list of them.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
class Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

var collection = new ObservableCollection<Entity>
{
    new Entity { Id = 1, Name = "Apple" },
    new Entity { Id = 2, Name = "Peach" },
    new Entity { Id = 3, Name = "Plum" },
    new Entity { Id = 4, Name = "Grape" },
    new Entity { Id = 5, Name = "Orange" },
};

collection.CollectionChanged += (sender, args) =>
{
    if (args.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove || args.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace)
    {
        for (var i = args.OldStartingIndex; i < collection.Count; i++)
        {
            collection[i].Id--;
        }
    }
};

collection.RemoveAt(2); // Grape.Id == 3, Orange.Id == 4
```

Comment: Didn't need a property changed event handler since the event is kinda automatically raised when the user presses a ListView item, but yes the for loop syntax works. Thanks.